# How to run same unit test multiple time to check active sessions on website? using ruby and java

Tags: ruby, testunit

I need to run login script in ruby multiple time to check active sessions which the web site can hold. How can I do that using ruby with test unit?

I am new to ruby so do not have much idea about the same. Kindly help.

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'selenium-webDriver'
require 'rubygems'
require 'Screenshot'


class Login_page < Test::Unit::TestCase
 def setup
    # setup for selenium webDriver with phantomjs
      @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

 #maximize the window
 @driver.manage.window.maximize

 #nevigate to test site
 @driver.navigate.to "https://www.findmedecor.com"

  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)

  screenshot()
 end

 def test_login

 # locate and open login overlay
 @driver.find_element(:class,'open-overlay').click

 wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
 screenshot()
 # Check that login pop up is displayed
 login_email = wait.until {
    element = @driver.find_element(:name, "login_email")
    element if element.displayed?
 }

 login_email.send_keys("suwarna.wade@rohagroup.com")
 puts "Test Passed: login pop up found" if login_email.displayed?
 screenshot()
 # locate and input data for password
 @driver.find_element(:id,'pass').send_keys('123456')

 # locate and click login button
 @driver.find_element(:id,'btn_login').click
 screenshot()
 puts "Logged in successfully"
 wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)

 #    add_proj = wait.until {
 #        element1 = @driver.find_element(:link, 'ADD NEW PROJECT')
 #        element1 if element1.displayed?        
 #        } 
 #        add_proj.click
 #        puts "redirected to edit project"
    clock= Time.new
    puts "Time of test = " +clock.inspect
    screenshot()
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post the login script?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this test? Is it a performance test, to see if the website can handle a large number of concurrent users? Is it a security test, to check that sessions expire? Is it a behaviour test, to check that the logout functionality works? ... Please include the relevant code in your post - such as the existing "unit test"(s) and how to are currently running it.

Comment: i need to check how much active sessions my website can handle without crashing. basically need to do load testing.

Comment: also how can i close all previously open browsers at a time when last test is running? cz with open browsers my system is crashing due to insufficient memory.